# R transforming multiple rows into columns

Tags: r

Hi all I have a table

```
id  sample_name replicates  raw 
a   control     c1          1   
a   control     c2          2   
a   control     c3          3   
b   control     c1          10    
b   control     c2          20   
b   control     c3          20
```

and would like to transform this to

```
id c1   c2   c3 
a  1    2    3    
b  10   20   20
```

The only way I know how to do this is to brute loop through every 3, because there are 3 replicates and append that to multiple vectors and recombine it at the end into a dataframe, thus I'm wondering if there is a more elegant/simple way to do this?  thanks!

Comment: Your data is in "long" form - you want it in "wide" form. Search the R tag for "long to wide" and you will find many examples, especially using `reshape2::dcast` or `tidyr::spread`.

Comment: `reshape2::dcast(df, id ~ replicates, value.var = 'raw')`

Comment: @alistaire thanks! exactly what I need.  Sorry for the redundancy.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
> library(reshape2)
> dcast(melt(df[, -2]), ...~replicates)[, -2]
Using id, replicates as id variables
  id c1 c2 c3
1  a  1  2  3
2  b 10 20 20
```